# NanoScroller not triggering itself

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

The code below should be able to trigger the `pane` and `slider` to appropriate `display` css properties according to [nanoscroller documentation](http://jamesflorentino.github.com/nanoScrollerJS/). However, the scroller doesn't show the `slider` until I do some action in browser such as pressing F12 to fireup firebug or right clicking an element inside to inspect it. What could possibly be going wrong?

```
        $(".nano").nanoScroller({
        alwaysVisible: true,
        scroll: "bottom"    
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like at least on version v0.7.4 if you call `nanoScroller()` with arguments the initialization of the plug-in could fail, above all with dynamic content.

If you are using `$('#yourDiv').animate()` be sure the call to `nanoScroller()` is done when the animation is finished. The same if you are using `$.getJSON()`, do it after the content has be fetched properly. If you are using both `animate()` and `getJSON()` call `nanoScroller()` after both events because it is unknow which process is going to finish first and several calls to `nanoScroller()` will not spoil anything.

And here the workaround is: call first `nanoScroller()` with no arguments and right after call it again if you require arguments.

```
$('.nano').nanoScroller();
$('.nano').nanoScroller({ alwaysVisible: true, scroll: 'top' });
```

Comment: This is going to seem incredibly random, but I just used this workaround and it fixed my problem! So thanks!

Comment: You are awesome buddy,

Answer (score 3):

This problem appears when **nanoscroller fails to initialize** properly for the element.

Make sure the element having the class nano is not within a parent element which is hidden with `display:none` CSS property.

In another case **if the content doesn't show up**, you would like to make sure **proper height  has been set** for the element having the class nano.

Answer (score 3):

In some cases, like mine, the nanoScroller needs to know the picture width/height first to work properly.

How I fixed it:

Instead of calling the function, with/without the .ready handler,

```
$(".nano").nanoScroller({
    alwaysVisible: true,
    scroll: "bottom"     
});
```

try the .load handler. Now JQuery only loads nanoScroller when the width/height of the pictures are known.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $(".nano").nanoScroller({
        alwaysVisible: true,
        scroll: "bottom"     
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're loading the content dynamically, you need to initialize nanoScroller only after the content is loaded.

Try to enclose nanoScroller initialization in a setTimeout like this.

```
setTimeout( function(){
    $('.nano').nanoScroller({ flashDelay: 1000 });
}, 0);
```

I had the same problem, this solved it for me.

Comment: +1 for `If you're loading the content dynamically, you need to initialize nanoScroller only after the content is loaded.`

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to trigger Nanoscroller after that all the content has been loaded; e.g. try to put the code above at the bottom of the page, or inserting some JQuery code to check that the page has finished loading content.

Answer (score 1):

My problem is the same with yours. Maybe the problem arises because i apply the nanoScroller function to the dynamically generated content. my solution is to add the the following line:

> $(".pane").css("display","block");
>   $(".slider").css("display","block");

and then the problem gone! If you check the page by "Inspect Element" function in Chrome, you can see the .pane class which the scroller (slider) exists show that

> style="display:none"

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct the code (jquery.nanoscroller.js)

```
if ((content.scrollHeight === content.clientHeight) || (this.pane.outerHeight(true) >= content.scrollHeight && contentStyleOverflowY !== SCROLL)) {
    this.pane.hide();
    /*this.isActive = false;*/
} else if (this.el.clientHeight === content.scrollHeight && contentStyleOverflowY === SCROLL) {
    this.slider.hide();
} else {
    this.slider.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is work like a charm in all cases event if your content resize or not. Try this:

```
$('your div id here').mouseover(function(){
     $('.nano').nanoScroller();
});
```